# UINavigationBar overflows out of screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

I am having this problem where I set my navigationbar into a tableview in storyboard, and when I launch the application, the navigationbar flows out of the screen. Somehow the width is too big but how can I change it so that it fits the screen?

[image: Storyboard]

[image: Application running]

Comment: Have you got constraints applied or autoresizing mask flags set?

Comment: @Tommy Thanks for your help. Finally found out that I hade the "User auto layout" flag triggered.

Comment: Oh, cool. I was unable to inspect too thoroughly owing to not having the Xcode beta installed. Sorry for vanishing.